# Get value of Biblatex's printfield{}

Tags: biblatex, ifthenelse

I would like to compare the value of a `\printfield` command in `\ifthenelse`

It seems printfield does not return the value so ifthenelse can't check it.

How can I access the value in a way that ifthenelse can use?

What I want to achieve is to check wether the value is greater than 9 (two-digit) and prepend a 0 if it is not.

Edit - MWE:

```tex
%Short literatur.bib 
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@Online{TEST2022,
  author   = {{Author}},
  title    = {Title},
  url      = {https://google.com},
  urldate  = {2022-06-02},
  date     = {2022},
  keywords = {test},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, labeldateparts=true, style=authortitle, isbn=false, dashed=false, maxnames=3, datezeroes=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\onlinezitat}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}
   \setunit{\addnbspace}
   online:
   \bibhyperref{\printnames[author]{labelname}}
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
   \newunit
   \printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extradate}
   \printtext{(}\printfield{urlday}\printtext{.}\printfield{urlmonth}\printtext{.}\printfield{urlyear}\printtext{)}}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{\bibsentence#1}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\begin{document}
Hallo\onlinezitat{TEST2022}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: \printfield prints, and printing instructions can normally not be viewed as value. You should better make a complete example that shows what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) [points out in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649188/get-value-of-biblatexs-printfield#comment1617988_649188), `\printfield` and friends are supposed to *print* the field contents and are not at all guaranteed to just expand to the value of the relevant field. That means that `\printfield` inside an `\ifthenelse` check is almost guaranteed to fail.

`biblatex` has an interface to retrieve field contents expandably (it does not offer such a feature for lists and name lists, since there is no natural single "value" associated to these lists, plus the internal representation of these lists is not very handy) with `\thefield`, e.g.

```
\thefield{entrykey}
```

`\thefield` can be extremely useful, but it almost always the wrong tool for the job if you want to format printed output. That is done much more naturally via `\DeclareFieldFormat` and friends.

In your example use case I would go for something else entirely, since dates should be printed with `\print...date` and not manually with `\printfield{...year}` etc.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  labeldateparts=true,
  style=authortitle,
  isbn=false,
  dashed=false,
  maxnames=3,
  datezeros=true,
]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{online}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  online = {online},
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\onlinezitat}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{####1}}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \bibstring{online}%
   \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
   \printdateextra
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \printurldate}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{\bibsentence#1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Online{TEST2022,
  author   = {{Author}},
  title    = {Title},
  url      = {https://google.com},
  urldate  = {2022-06-02},
  date     = {2022},
  keywords = {test},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Hallo\onlinezitat{TEST2022}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Online: Author 2022 (02.06.2022)]